# Setting up local web server on Mac for Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I use MAMP for PHP/MySQL.

What do I need for RoR?

I am using OS X Leopard.  I have already installed Ruby, Gems and Rails.

Comment: This is better suited for serverfault.com

Comment: This is a development question. Serverfault is more fitted for "how do I deploy Rails into production?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo gem install passenger` will get you [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) (mod_rails) which is pretty much the standard nowadays. There's a nice [preference pane](http://www.fngtps.com/2009/09/new-os-more-pane-passenger-preference-pane-v1-3) for managing the server on Mac OS X and a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/122-passenger-in-development) about it.

Alternatively, `sudo gem install mongrel` to use the [Mongrel](http://mongrel.rubyforge.org/) server which you run using the `script/server` command and access on port 3000. Rails includes the basic WEBrick server, but most developers use Mongrel or Passenger.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on rails has a builtin web server (Webrick)

so you have only to create a rails project:

```
rails your_project
cd your_project
```

and start the server:

```
script/server
```

edit:
also you can use mongrel instead of webrick by simply installing the gem

```
(sudo) gem install mongrel
```

if have a lot of apps that you want to run automatically at startup you sure can use Apache  with [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com)  (aka: mod_rack or mod_rails)

and the [Passenger Pane](http://www.fngtps.com/2008/06/putting-the-pane-back-into-deployment) may be useful (tnx fingertips)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run `script/server` to run a local web server for web development - there is no need to set up something like Apache. It will tell you the port it is listening at, and then you can just open that in your web browser.

You might want to install Mongrel (a faster Ruby server) by typing:

`sudo gem install mongrel`

Then `script/server` will use that instead of the default, WEBrick.

When deploying to production, you might be interested in something like [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/), but it's much easier to develop applications using the built-in way.